# Quartz Plugin Error on Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler

I installed Quartz Plugin in a grails project but when I compile , It gives me the following error.

```
Error loading plugin manager: startup failed:
C:\Users\X\.grails\1.3.7\projects\Val\plugins\quartz-0.4.2\QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy: 116: You cannot create an instance from the abstract interface 'org.quartz.CronTrigger'.
 @ line 116, column 35.
                   Trigger trigger = new CronTrigger(generateTriggerName(), GTCP.DEFAULT_TRIGGERS_GROUP, jobName, jobGroup, cronExpression)
                                     ^
C:\Users\X\.grails\1.3.7\projects\Val\plugins\quartz-0.4.2\QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy: 122: You cannot create an instance from the abstract interface 'org.quartz.SimpleTrigger'.
 @ line 122, column 35.
                   Trigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger(generateTriggerName(), GTCP.DEFAULT_TRIGGERS_GROUP, jobName, jobGroup, new Date(), null, repeatCount, interval)
                                     ^
C:\Users\X\.grails\1.3.7\projects\Val\plugins\quartz-0.4.2\QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy: 128: You cannot create an instance from the abstract interface 'org.quartz.SimpleTrigger'.
 @ line 128, column 35.
                   Trigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger(generateTriggerName(), GTCP.DEFAULT_TRIGGERS_GROUP, jobName, jobGroup, scheduleDate, null, 0, 0)
                                     ^
C:\Users\X\.grails\1.3.7\projects\Val\plugins\quartz-0.4.2\QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy: 133: You cannot create an instance from the abstract interface 'org.quartz.SimpleTrigger'.
 @ line 133, column 35.
                   Trigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger(generateTriggerName(), GTCP.DEFAULT_TRIGGERS_GROUP, jobName, jobGroup, scheduleDate, null, 0, 0)
                                     ^
4 errors
```

and this is what I am trying to achieve...

```
class MyJob  {
  static triggers = {
    cron name: 'myTrigger', cronExpression: "0 0 6 * * ?"
  }
 def group = "MyGroup"

 def execute(){
   print "Job run!"
 }
}
```

Note: Plugin version is 0.4.2

Comment: I think you need to add a bit more details (like what version grails you are using). I have recently installed and used this plugin and it has run flawlessly. Where do you have the MyJob class? This should be created using >grails create-job MyJob        , Sorry I can't be of much help.

Comment: Thank you for responding @ibaralf. I used the following command. grails create-job MyJob but before that grails install-plugin quartz command is issued. I am using grails 1.3.7 and MyJob is under grails-app/jobs/val/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really can't reproduce it. I created a new project and installed the plugin and it runs perfectly. You're not trying to create an instance of the MyJob class, right? Basically, once installed, this class (the job) is ready to run. It will get triggered depending on the setting on the cronExpression.

Here are the steps I took to test your scenario:

1) Create grails app:

> grails create-app testquartz

2) install plugin:

> grails install-plugin quartz

3) create a new job:

> grails create-job my

4) edit the MyJob class:

```
class MyJob  {
  static triggers = {
    cron name: 'myTrigger', cronExpression: "* * * * * ?"
  }
 def group = "MyGroup"

 def execute(){
   print "Job run!"
 }
}
```

5) Run the application:

> grails run-app

=> You should see the text "Job run" printed out every second since the cronExpression would trigger it for every second. Inside execute() is where you would put the code which you want to be executed by your cron job. I suggest creating a service and putting the code to run in the service and call it inside the execute() method.

Comment: Thats funny. I was going to write exactly what you wrote today but you are just quicker than me. I created a new project and installed quartz it runs perfectly however this is not the case for my main project.

Comment: my friend, "grails clean" command did the trick but I am not able to uninstall quartz now :)

Comment: since your answer is correct, I vote for it. Thank you again.